# Is there a production grade SimpleDB .NET library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

- [Here you will find all the SimpleDB code samples on the AWS page.](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=2382&categoryID=148)
- [Here you will find a VB.NET SimpleDB library.](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1134)

Is there a production grade SimpleDB library, preferable built in C#. If not, May I use the VB.NET library on a C# project as a reference?

Answer (score 8):

Amazon just recently released the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/).  It's a step up from their prior offerings as far as I've seen (though I'm admittedly *very* new to the AWS thus far.)

Comment: The AWS SDK for .NET simply repackages Amazon's prior offerings for various services into a single library. The biggest change is that Amazon is now committed to maintaining and versioning these libraries that were previously released as demonstration projects.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Mindscape's](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/) [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx) that supports SimpleDB ORM out of the box. They have a beta product called [SimpleDB Management Tools](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/simpledbtools/default.aspx) for $29 USD that is in beta, but these guys produce great software so my suggestion would be to investigate and feedback to them.

The plus side is you get a great ORM for other uses.

Comment: Just for info, SimpleDB Management Tools is now in full production release.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out [Simol](http://simol.codeplex.com/), an open-source .NET persistence library designed specifically for SimpleDB (I'm the creator). The first release was several years ago, and it's in use by quite a few applications. I keep a partial list of the applications I know about [here](http://simol.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Applications%20Using%20Savant&referringTitle=Documentation).

Answer (score 2):

For a commercially supported solution, check out the /n software Amazon Integrator - http://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/amazon.  Includes components for .NET, as well as Java, C++, COM, Delphi etc.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon provides a C# version of their SimpleDB library at http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1133

But also: assuming you have Visual Studio or at least the .NET Framework SDK, you could compile Amazon's SimpleDB library as a DLL, then include the file and reference it in your C# project and that would work pretty much the same way.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you will find a C# SimpleDB library](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1133)

There's also an open source SimpleDB provider, which you can find [here](http://www.codeplex.com/LinqToSimpleDB), which might come in handy.

Comment: Have you used the SimpleDB provider (Linq2SQL), it looks like it has not been maintained.  Any opinions?

Comment: "Error. We were unable to find the page you requested"

Comment: Link is dead.  Looks like new link is http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Stratosphere](http://stratosphere.codeplex.com/). It's open source, C#, Mono compatible library for SimpleDB, SQS and S3. Supports latest conditional updates and consistent reads. Includes local implementation based on SQLite that closely mimics SimpleDB for unit testing etc. Also has local file system implementations for S3 and SQS APIs. Additional download contains command line utility for managing SimpleDB, SQS and S3.

Answer (score 1):

I just released a library on my site for free.  I'm using it for our internal applications and have made it available for anyone else that wants to use it.  The library uses T4 Text Templates to code generate classes for each domain.  It uses the GNU software license.

You can download the entire solution including source code at http://www.exspartners.com/SimpleDBDotNetLibrary.aspx.